# Creating average for specific timeframe

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm setting up a time series with each row = 1 hr.
The input data has sometimes multiple values per hour. This can vary.

Right now the specific code looks like this:

```
select
patientunitstayid
, generate_series(ceil(min(nursingchartoffset)/60.0), 
ceil(max(nursingchartoffset)/60.0)) as hr
, avg(case when nibp_systolic >= 1 and nibp_systolic <= 250 then 
nibp_systolic else null end) as nibp_systolic_avg
from nc            
group by patientunitstayid
order by patientunitstayid asc;
```

and generates this data:

[image]

It takes the average of the entire time series for each patient instead of taking it for each hour. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm expecting something like this:

```
select nc.patientunitstayid, gs.hr, 
       avg(case when nc.nibp_systolic >= 1 and nc.nibp_systolic <= 250 
                then nibp_systolic 
           end) as nibp_systolic_avg
from (select nc.*,
             min(nursingchartoffset) over (partition by patientunitstayid) as min_nursingchartoffset,
             max(nursingchartoffset) over (partition by patientunitstayid) as max_nursingchartoffset
      from nc
     ) nc cross join lateral
     generate_series(ceil(min_nursingchartoffset/60.0), 
                     ceil(max_nursingchartoffset/60.0)
                    ) as gs(hr)
group by nc.patientunitstayid, hr
order by nc.patientunitstayid asc, hr asc;
```

That is, you need to be aggregating by `hr`.  I put this into the `from` clause, to highlight that this generates *rows*.  If you are using an older version of Postgres, then you might not have lateral joins.  If so, just use a subquery in the `from` clause.

EDIT:

You can also try:

```
from (select nc.*,
             generate_series(ceil(min(nursingchartoffset) over (partition by patientunitstayid) / 60.0), 
                             ceil(max(nursingchartoffset) over (partition by patientunitstayid)/ 60.0)
                            ) hr
      from nc
     ) nc
```

And adjust the references to `hr` in the outer query.

Comment: It's not possible to put functions in the FROM-clause, so how do you implement this in another way?

Comment: @bzoei . . . It *is* possible using a lateral join.  You must be using an old version of Postgres.

Comment: Thank you, the subquery in the `From` clause seems to work. I am using pgAdmin 4 version 3.6 and PostgreSQL 11, so it's weird the lateral join doesn't work.

Comment: @bzoei . . . I'm glad it is working for you.  But Postgres 11 definitely supports lateral joins, and lateral joins with `generate_series()`.  Here is an example:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b6dda6d4f80fcc2d13ece03c4e465eee.

Comment: @bzoei . . . Never mind.  The problem is the aggregation.  I hadn't realized that the limits come from aggregation, so I fixed the answer.